# How to show a popup with text when a game object is selected?

Tags: c#, unity, gui

We're building an FPS game where you walk around a 3D environment and walk up to objects, click, and then a GUI message pops up.

Basically, I've got a character, walking around in 3D space, and is using a raycast to interact with things. However, I can't figure out how to hook on a UI pop up.

I'm writing in C# because that's what the original tutorial is in. I tried checking out tutorials on how to make a pause menu appear (thinking I could just hook a pause pop up to the raycast clicking action) but all the tutorials are in JS or were written prior to Unity 4.6 UI manager implementation.

So any clue on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Interaction with the UI, and by the UI is primarily done via events. You can learn about activating code with the UI from [the official Unity tutorial on the subject](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-events-and-event-triggers).

However, it sounds like you're more interested in finding out how to show a UI element based on a code event. The easiest way to accomplish this is simply toggling the UI object's `enabled` property.

I'd probably put a script on all the objects you're raycasting at, giving them some information about what should be displayed in the pop up. Something like `MyTextInfoScript` would have a public string called `textForPopUp` that would contain the text the pop up is supposed to display when the raycast hits the object.

For example, when your ray hits an object you're interested in, and you want to activate a pop up, set your pop up canvas element to enabled and set it's text to the text you want to show for that object. You don't show how you're doing the ray casting, but it could be something like:

```
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, out hit, maxRayDistance, layerMask))
    popupCanvas.enabled = true;
    MyTextInfoScript textInfo = hit.gameObject.GetComponent<MyTextInfoScript>();
    popupText.text = textInfo.textForPopUp;
}
```

Where `popupCanvas` and `popupText` are references to the canvas for your pop up element and the text component inside the pop up.

Comment: This is how I ended up structuring my code: 
  
http://i.imgur.com/rKzEiYf.png 
    
http://i.imgur.com/jI7C0n7.png 

Is using the enable property different than the SetActive? How so?